# What's the difference between ContextMenuInfo.id and item.getItemId in the callback onContextItemSelected()?

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu

What's the difference between **ContextMenuInfo.id** and item.getItemId in the callback **onContextItemSelected**()?

How can I display a **ContextMenu** in my **AVD**? Thank you!!

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.edit:
    editNote(info.id);
    return true;
  case R.id.delete:
    deleteNote(info.id);
    return true;
  default:
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inflate the menu before passing it into super.onCreateContextMenu.

ContextMenuInfo is the extra data that the view that initiated the context menu can setup - so there are edit and delete buttons with different item.getItemId(), but info.id gives the view that was used to create the menu (the item to be edited).

Comment: Thank you! Then how to change info.id in **menuInfo**?